# WiFi on my Nexus S no longer works after update to ICS - How can I troubleshoot or fix this?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I just updated My Nexus S to ICS today and everything is working properly except for WiFi. It shows the network's SSID but says it is "Out of range". How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the official ICS update for the nexus s? if not official, what ROM are you using? Are you sure there isn't known WiFi issues?

Comment: it doesn't depend on whether you updated manually or via official OTA (look below)

Answer (score 1):

That's right, this is known issue and you are not alone. Unfortunately there is no official way to fix this. The only way to get your WiFi working properly is to remove your SIM card or use American (USA) sim card.

BTW it doesn't depend on whether you updated manually or via official OTA.

I suppose, the problem is with latest kernel which doesn't support other country codes despite US and EU. The new kernel is getting the country code from SIM card and after finding that it's neither EU nor US it's dropping wifi support. Unfortunately I don't know exactly why.

There are some workarounds however, they require Rooted device. You can install custom ROM's (unsigned!) or use some scripts (from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1372074&page=7)

You can "star" the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23262 so as many people would "star" it as more attention it could get.

People also saying that there are some missing features after upgrading
like:

- No Face Unlock.
- No Camera Zoom.
- No Zero Shutter lag
- No Android Beam for Images.

P.S: As far as I know Google stopped providing ICS OTA for Nexus S. I hope they are aware of that issue and working on it.